# What makes two arrays map to the same cache line?

Tags: c++, c, caching

```
for ( i =0; i < 2; i++)
for( j  = 0 ; j < 2: j++)
dst[j][i] = src[i][j];
```

For a cache with 8 byte cache lines and a total cache size of 16 bytes, 
The answer key says 
"Notice that each cache line holds exactly one row of the array, that the cache is exactly large enough to hold one array, and that for row i of src and dst maps to the same cache line.
"

So this mapping causes very specific eviction. Instead of src having miss only for [0][0] and [1][0], it also misses [0][1] because the first cache line was evicted and replaced with dst [0][0] [0][1]. Why didn't the cache evict the second cache line which may have contained either nothing or src's [1][0] [1][1]. Why do src and dst's 0 rows have to map to the same cache line?  What determines this?

Answer (score 1):

Typical cache implementations use address bits to select which cache set an address is held in. Which bits may vary from implementation to implementation, as well as whether virtual address or physical address bits are used.

The problem statement is telling you that the addresses of `src` and `dst` are such that they map to the same cache set as each other. This also means that, for any `i`, `src+i` and `dst+i` will map to the same cache set as each other.

For example, suppose, on a 32-bit architecture, address bits 10-3 are used by hardware to select the cache set. Bits 2-0 index the eight bytes within each line. When the processor wants to load or store an address, the hardware uses bits 10-3 to select a cache set. A cache set may be capable of holding multiple lines. Each line in cache will contain a tag that records bits 31-11 of the address it corresponds to. So the hardware will compare bits 31-11 of the current address with the tags of the lines in the set. If none match, it picks one of the lines in the set to evict, then replaces it with the new line.

We can see from this behavior with multiple lines in a set that the hardware is capable of holding a choice of lines in a cache set. But it takes a lot of hardware to do this—when a line is being considered, the hardware has to evaluate every line in a set. It is a lot easier to do this for just four lines in a set rather than for the thousands of lines in the entire cache. So hardware is built with just a limited amount of this capability. It is a lot cheaper solution but gives some flexibility about which lines are held in cache.

The problem description you provide seems to be suggesting that each cache set can hold just one line (although it is not clear about this). That means the old line is evicted as soon as a new line using the same cache set is used. That is pretty restrictive and is usually avoided when designing hardware today. But it may be suitable for some tutorial examples.